# fgets to stop when a space is encountered

Tags: c, parsing, fgets, scanf

I am trying to parse a input JSON file in C and the contents of the file are something like: `{"version":"0.1","type":"tracbuf:e", "userid":0, "method":"udpbuf:-paris", "src":"10.20.6.191"buf:, "dst":"8.8.8.8", "sport":41buf:687, "dport":33435, ...`

The input file is quite big and I want to read every line and parse the read line i.e., separate the key-value pairs respectively and the lines and key-value fields are arbitrary in length.

I know it works fine with `fscanf()`. But I would like to use some function with bounds protection such as `fgets()`. But I'm not quite sure how to use fgets() in this case because it reads the 'n' bytes into the buffer including new line, tab space and `blankspace('')`. But I want to be able to break once a blank space / tab space/  newline character is encountered for parsing the read characters before reading the other lines further.

Please note that `fscanf()` can do this along with `strtok()` - it breaks with every space/new line. But sadly, it doesn't allow bounds on the buffer.

How do I go about?

Update Edit:

The below approach works.  Inside every conditional, I need to invoke strtok and around 6 comparisons are made. But I would like to know if this can be done even better.

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%100s", buf) != EOF)

{
token=strtok(buf,":-");

while(token!=NULL)

{

if(strcmp(token,"\"src\"")==0) 

{ 

head[trace_count]=(HEADER*) malloc(sizeof(HEADER));

token=strtok(NULL,":{,}])");

strcpy(head[trace_count]->src_ip,token);

}   
else if(strcmmp(...))
{
}

...
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` does allow bounds on the buffer, but all of this sounds like a horrible idea (especially since JSON doesn't structurally require spaces (and why would you want to stop in the middle of a string that happens to contain a space?)).

Comment: Are you really sure you want to roll your own json parser ? There are *interesting* corner cases such as strings containing commas (`,`), double quotes (`"`), and so on that will need extensive testing ... and will break any attempt to use tools as simple as `fscanf` or `strtok` :-( - That being said, it is certainly possible if you can be sure that those *corner cases* cannot occur here, but then you should say what are your requirements since it is no longer a generic json parser.

Comment: @melpomene How does fscanf allow bounds on the buffer? And I would like to stop in the middle to store some necessary key-value pairs(say "src" and "dst" values) and not all the pairs! What will be the right thing to do?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I agree with you! It's a bit risky to do the parsing directly. I managed to find most of the corner cases and tried to pass them and it did- All of it was using fscanf and strtok. But now I need to use something with bounds protection- so should refrain from using fscanf. Please give me your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%100s", buf)` or whatever

Comment: @melpomene - Thanks! Then why is it a good practice to use fgets() or something similar over fscanf()?

Comment: `fgets` and `fscanf` are simply different things. First is to use where input is line oriented.

Comment: What is the longest acceptable line of your input?

Comment: @chux, that's hard to say. I have a very large file to read and parse-- the file size is variable in length. Not sure if streaming IO will be a good choice. Do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: IMO, with variable length lines, robust code handles _very_ long lines.  Yet incredible long lines are a security threat as they are more likely a hacker's exploit than a legitimatize use.  So _some_ upper bound is prudent with a detection and error message on excessively long lines.  In this learning case, examine your longest line in your data and use an upper bound of at least 2x for the code.  Do not hardcore a value throughout code - use something like `#define LINE_SIZE_MAX (1024)` and then `LINE_SIZE_MAX` elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lines can be any length, you will always have a problem reading a line into a buffer; the buffer could potentially never be large enough. The only way is by character processing. The following is a simple, basic parser for your syntax. Adapt as you need:

```
void example(FILE *fin)
{
    char c, token[MAX_TOKEN], tokval[MAX_SVAL], *s= token;
    int instr= FALSE;   // track whether we are in a string
    int intok= TRUE;    // track whether we are in a token name or a value

    while ((c=fgetc(fin)) != EOF)
    {
        if (instr) {
            if (c=='"')
                 {*s='\0'; instr= FALSE;}
            else *s++ = c;
        }
        else switch (c) {
        case '"': instr= TRUE; break;
        case '{': /* open:  whatever you want to do*/ break;
        case '}': /* close: whatever you want to do*/ break;
        case ':': if (intok)  {*s= '\0'; s= tokval; intok= FALSE; /* have token name now*/} else *s++ = ':'; break;
        case ',': if (!intok) {*s= '\0'; s= token;  intok= TRUE;  /* have a pair now    */} else *s++ = ','; break;
        case ' ': case '\t': case '\n': case '\r': break;
        default: *s++ = c;
        }
        if (intok)
             {if (s > token+MAX_TOKEN-2) error("token name too long");}
        else {if (s > tokval+MAX_SVAL-2) error("token value too long");}
    }   
}
```

Comment: `char c` --> `int c` so code may distinguish `EOF` from all other `char`.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie: Thanks for the suggestion! Will try this out.